# Помогите построить трехтабличный SQL-запрос

Tags: sql

Есть 3 таблицы

```
content:
id|name|text

category:
id|name

contact:
id_content|id_category
```

Мне нужно получить все категории, одного из контента, и вывести их названия.

тобишь в результате: контент => (категория1, категория5, категория20)

Comment: А что имеете на входе? content.id, content.name или что-то другое?

Comment: @Deonis на входе content.id

Comment: @rnddev, потестировать [можно тут][1]

    SELECT 
      `cat`.`name`
    FROM
      `category` `cat`
      INNER JOIN `contact` `cont` ON (`cat`.`id` = `cont`.`id_category`)
    WHERE
      `cont`.`id_content` = ?

   [1]:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e3b8/3/0

Comment: @Deonis благодарю.

Answer (score 5):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Deonis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4058/deonis)*

```
SELECT
  cat.name
FROM
  category cat
INNER JOIN
  contact cont
ON
  cat.id = cont.id_category
WHERE
  cont.id_content = ?
```